# PhoneGap Android project reference in Eclipse

Tags: javascript, android, eclipse, cordova

I am attempting to do three projects at once using PhoneGap - a mobile website, an Android app, and an iOS app. I am starting the Andriod portion of this project now and I don't want to have to do any copying of files from my mobile site project into the PhoneGap assets/www directory when I build my Android app in Eclipse. Both the Android and mobile site projects are in the same workspace in Eclipse. Is there a way I can reference my mobile site project so that it gets built within the assets/www folder of the Android PhoneGap project when I build in Eclipse? Is this a native function of Eclipse or am I going to have to use some build script? Any ideas?

[image]

So in this image, I want the www folder to essentially be replaced with another whole project on build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are on a UNIX based system you could do a symlink from www to the contents of your mobile website. However, Eclipse is really bad at detecting that a file has changed outside of it's environment so you'll want to do a project->refresh frequently to make sure you've got the latest code.

Comment: Thanks, this works. You're right, the project refresh is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think so that u can create a reference of a web project into a assets/www.

But i can suggest u one thing that can be implemented:- make a copy of web project in www folder and now make all edits for web and android in this folder.

U can use www folder even in website.